# How can we strip spaces before writing into csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, weka

```
!   #   $   %   &   (   )   *       ,   -   0   /   :           <   =   >   ?   @   [   \   ]   ^
```

this the header of my csv file.. after **:** you can see one blank space like my csv file header also contain one column with  header blank.how can remove by updating following code??

```
feature_list = "" 
root_flag = 'false' 
fvt_length = 0

output_file="/home/user/Project/Dataset/unigram_FVT.csv"   

feature_vector_file1 = "/home/user/Project/Dataset/BST_unigram.txt"         
d = os.path.dirname(output_file)
if not os.path.exists(d):
    os.makedirs(d)

with open(output_file, "w" ) as fout:
    fp_feature = csv.writer(fout)        
    fileread=open(feature_vector_file1,"r")
    read_list=fileread.read()

    read_list=dataPreprocessing.remove_words_less_than_3(read_list)

    read_list = read_list.replace('\n','')
    read_list =  re.sub( '\s+', ' ',read_list).strip()
    read_list = dataPreprocessing.remove_digits(read_list)
    unigram_list=list(set(read_list.split(" ")))

    for i in range(0,len(unigram_list)):
        unigram_list[i]=unigram_list[i].lstrip().rstrip()
        if root_flag == 'false' :
            root = Node(unigram_list[i])
            root_flag = 'true'
        else :
            root.insert(unigram_list[i])
        feature_list = feature_list + "\n"+unigram_list[i]

        feature_list1 = feature_list.strip()
        line = feature_list1.split('\n')
        line.sort()
        line.append("Gender")
        root.print_tree()
        print len(line)
        fp_feature.writerow(line)
        FVT_unigram()
```

Can anybody can help me? Sometimes my file content contains some spaces but I have added this  `unigram_list[i]=unigram_list[i].lstrip().rstrip()` but still my header contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with  my program the other day, and I realized the easiest thing to do is ato write a simple if statement and just create a new string/list:

```
aStr = "Hello World this is a test!"
newStr = ""
for letter in aStr:
    if letter!=" ":
    newStr += letter
```

And when I print the newStr:
HelloWorldthisisatest!